# How to not update React component on each change in state?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux

I use Redux and a Websocket connection to server to retrieve data. Amount of data is about 200k rows that go into my app one by one as Websocket messages. Once a row comes, I want to save it in the state with Redux, which I know how to do and it works just fine.

The issue I am foreseeing, is that I don't want to update the view every time a single row is being added into the state.

The idea is to debounce updating a view each, say, 10 seconds, or may be on each 10k rows.

How should I make it work properly? I am more interested in a described concept, rather than detailed technical solution.

Thanks!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: You could potentially use [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) to only render the rows that are currently on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the component's `shouldComponentUpdate` to reject a re-render when the state changes; something like this -

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // only re-render when you have data worth 10x rows
    return nextState.arrayOfRows % 10 === 0;
  }

  render() {
    // render logic here 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to control the component should update or not with [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) like [@RaghudevanShankar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47219431/2315280).

Another option can be to update redux state periodically. For example rather than adding records on every message/row you can combine them into batches and then run your action with an array of row data.